# How to resolve the issue of WhatsApp sharing not functioning in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am tiring to write code to share text via `WhatsApp` , but even the `WhatsApp` is installed on my device I get `"WhatsApp is not installed on the device"`

I am using Kotlin.

```
class TestViewModel(private val context: Context) : ViewModel()
{

    fun shareTextViaWhatsApp(text: String) {
        
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.type = "text/plain"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)

        // Set package name to limit sharing via WhatsApp only
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

        // Verify that WhatsApp is installed on the device
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            // WhatsApp is not installed, show an error message or fallback to another method
            Toast.makeText(context, " WhatsApp is not installed on the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding *queries* section to the manifest as a direct child of `<manifest` tag:

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
```

Comment: The code worked! Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @HamidMohammed Happy to hear that! If you find my answer useful, please mark it as a correct answer, so other users could easily find it